# OGR - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateLayer'

Tags: shapefile, ogr

I have an error when i wan't to create a `Shapefile` layer with `OGR`. When I run my script for the first time, everything all right, layer is well created. But when i run it for the second time `CreateDataSource()` is None and `CreateLayer()` returns an error. If i run it a third time, it works again.

If i look at the [documentation](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#delete-a-file) everything seems ok. How to explain and prevent this ?

```
import osgeo.ogr as ogr
import os

output="full/path/to/my/layer.shp"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
if os.path.exists(output):    
    driver.DeleteDataSource(output)
ds = driver.CreateDataSource(output)
layer = ds.CreateLayer(output, geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
```

Comment: Is this on a normal local filesystem? Does the actually get deleted?

Comment: Yes it's on a local classic filesystem. Files don't get deleted, `.dbf` and `.shp` are still here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With researches, this behaviour is a [Python gotcha](https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#saving-and-closing-datasets-datasources). Data source must be dereference.

```
import osgeo.ogr as ogr
import os

output="full/path/to/my/layer.shp"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
if os.path.exists(output):    
    driver.DeleteDataSource(output)
ds = driver.CreateDataSource(output)
layer = ds.CreateLayer(output, geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
ds = None
```